# Adding HTML link inside a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using a plugin called [Wp-moo-tree](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-moo-tree/)

The purpose of this plugin is to display a hierarchical tree, similar to widows explorer folder tree some thing as follows

-- Folder-1
----- Folder-1.1
----- Folder-1.2

The HTML coding of above hierarchical tree displayed inside the DOM (document object model) is

```
  <div>Folder-1</div>
  <div>Folder-1.1</div>
  <div>Folder-1.2</div>
```

which is parsed from a HTML query as follows

```
  <a href="folder1.html">Folder-1</a>
  <a href="folder1.1.html">Folder-1.1</a>
  <a href="folder1.2.html">Folder-1.2</a>
```

My issue is I want to add the link (a href) portion also, along with "Folder-1" in the DOM parsed hierarchical tree as follows

```
  <div><a href="folder1.html">Folder-1</a></div>
```

How can I do this? Anyone have idea about which portion of Javascript is doing this in wp-mootree?

Answer (score 1):

The features list right on [the page you linked to](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-moo-tree/) lists what you seem to be looking for:

> *If you would like the branch to link to a url, you have a field for that (note: the javascript would need to be changed).*

Clicking through to the support section, there's an entire [discussion of just the feature you seem to desire](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/link-to-page-url), and the means of implementing it.

Which brings me to a comment: had you expended just a *tiny* bit of effort (definitely less effort than it took you to type your question here) you would have likely found these on your own. I answer trusting that you actually *did* endeavor a good-faith effort to find an answer and somehow, *inexplicably,* came up empty.

Now, if somehow you *did* see the support link and you *still* have these questions, then you did an even worse job framing your question than I imagined. But if you didn't know about the discussion of the feature you're inquiring about, again, [here it is](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/link-to-page-url).

Comment: Thanks for your response !! According to the discussion involved in the link, unfortunately it is not coming to the exact requirement what I needed